# How to use the Google api-client python library for Google Logging

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I've been using the **Google apiclient library** in python for various Google Cloud APIs - mostly for Google Compute - with great success.

I want to start using the library to create and control the **Google Logging mechanism** offered by the  Google Cloud Platform.

However, this is a beta version, and I can't find any real documentation or example on how to use the logging API.

All I was able to find are high-level descriptions such as:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/logging/v1beta3/

Can anyone provide a simple example on how to use **apiclient** for logging purposes? 
for example creating a new log entry...

Thanks for the help

Shahar

Answer (score 0):

I found this page:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging

Which states you can do the following to set the log level:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

However it doesn't seem to have any impact on the output which is always INFO for me.

I also tried setting httplib2 to debuglevel 4:

```
import httplib2
httplib2.debuglevel = 4
```

Yet I don't see any HTTP headers in the log :/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but it is getting some attention, so I guess it might be worth answering to it, in case someone else comes here.

[Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries) for Google Cloud Platform are not in beta anymore, as they hit General Availability some time ago. The link I shared contains the most relevant documentation for installing and using them.

After running the command `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-logging`, you will be able to authenticate with your GCP account, and use the Client Libraries.

Using them is as easy as importing the library with a command such as `from google.cloud import logging`, then instantiate a new client (which you can use by default, or even pass the *Project ID* and *Credentials* explicitly) and finally work with Logs as you want.

You may also want to visit the [official library documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/usage.html), where you will find all the details of how to use the library, which methods and classes are available, and how to do most of the things, with lots of self-explanatory examples, and even comparisons between the different alternatives on how to interact with Stackdriver Logging.

As a small example, let me also share a snippet of how to retrieve the five most recent logs which have status more sever than "warning":

```
# Import the Google Cloud Python client library
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging import DESCENDING

# Instantiate a client
logging_client = logging.Client(project = <PROJECT_ID>)

# Set the filter to apply to the logs, this one retrieves GAE logs from the default service with a severity higher than "warning"
FILTER = 'resource.type:gae_app and resource.labels.module_id:default and severity>=WARNING'

i = 0
# List the entries in DESCENDING order and applying the FILTER
for entry in logging_client.list_entries(order_by=DESCENDING, filter_=FILTER):  # API call
    print('{} - Severity: {}'.format(entry.timestamp, entry.severity))
    if (i >= 5):
        break
    i += 1
```

Bear in mind that this is just a simple example, and that many things can be achieved using the Logging Client Library, so you should refer to the official documentation pages that I shared in order to get a more deep understanding of how everything works.

Answer (score 0):

> However it doesn't seem to have any impact on the output which is
> always INFO for me.

add a logging handler, e.g.:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(process)d %(levelname)s:  %(message)s')                                     
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()                                                                                 
consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)                                                                                       
consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)                                                                                   
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```